# How to prevent text changes during afterTextChange() from breaking Korean character composition

Tags: android, android-edittext, internationalization, cjk

We have logic to auto replace spaces with hyphens in an input box because spaces are invalid for that field. It works great in all languages so far, but in Korean that causes character composition to break. The cause isn’t the hyphen itself, but updating the `Editable` in `afterTextChanged(s: Editable)` Here’s what I mean by composition

Before:

`ㄱㅣㅁ` is transformed into `김`

After:

`김-ㄱㅣㅁ` the three characters after the hyphen are not transformed into a single one

I've narrowed it down to the line that actually replaces the text:

`s.replace(0, s.length, newName)`

When I remove that line it works, so I know it's not the hyphen character itself that causes the issue, but the string replacement. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: `s` is a `StringBuilder`? But then `s.length()` expected.

Comment: How is newName created? That seems to be done wrong.